# Refresh (not reload) iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to figure out how to refresh the contents of an iFrame on a page. I did quite a bit of Googling and hunting around through old posts, but all of the solutions offered are for reloading an iFrame to the initial src URL, and not the active URL.

For example, I have an iFrame that contains my Freshdesk client portal embedded into my main website. If I click around to a couple of different pages within the iFrame, I then want to be able to intercept a page refresh and simply refresh the iFrame to the active page.

Current Behavior:
Freshdesk Home --> Knowledgebase --> New Ticket --> Refresh --> Back to home

Desired Behavior:
Freshdesk Home --> Knowledgebase --> New Ticket --> Refresh --> Back to new ticket screen (the last page visited in the iFrame before triggering the refresh)

The refresh doesn't have to be triggered by an f5 refresh, I can use an inline button on the page, but it needs to reload the iFrame to the same page that it was last on, not the original src URL. I tried the following code, but it refreshes to the home page of my Freshdesk every time:

`document.getElementById('iframeid').src = document.getElementById('iframeid').src`

and

`document.getElementById('some_frame_id').contentWindow.location.reload();`

So, how can I refresh my iFrame without restarting back to the original src URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onbeforeunload` event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload to detect that the page is going to be closed or refreshed.

So you can then compare the active src and the original src of the iframe to know if the user navigated to some page inside the iframe.

Then choose your favourite message passing system to make sure the portal has a way to know that src after it loaded again: url parameter, local storage, cookie, something else...

Comment: My specific problem lies in getting the iFrame to refresh to the same page that it was on before the refresh. I can intercept the refresh just fine, but the iFrame keeps refreshing back to the main src page, and not to the last page it was on...

Comment: Since the iframe is embedded in the portal page, you need to make sure the portal page checks for this on load. For example, the easiest way to pass data is through the url. So when you detect that the portal page will refresh, block that and load www.myportal.com?ticket=123 or something instead. Then inside the portal page, you can just detect if the url the portal was opened with, contains a ticket number and update the iframe src if needed. Same with local storage, but instead of checking the url, check the storage if there was an active ticket.

Comment: The iFrame is on my own website. The portal page is what's inside the iFrame. They are on two separate URLs so CORS rules apply... Also, the portal's code and logic is not accessible to me as it's controlled by Freshdesk. I can only control the code on my own website.

Comment: Doesn't the same logic apply? Freshdesk has a url to directly open a specific ticket right? Your own website just needs to update the src of the iframe to that url so the portal opens upon the ticket instead of the home page. And you know which src it has to be by passing it between reloads.

Comment: That's the part I think I'm confused on... I'm not sure how to get the active URL of the iFrame in order to reload it and pass the data back in. I haven't been able to figure out any way to get the active URL of the iFrame...

Comment: You have tried `contentWindow.location.href` ? It gives me a full location string of an iframe, including the hash and the query part. This does rely on freshdesk actually having a direct route to the ticket.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, and it doesn't work due to XSS / CORS restrictions.

Comment: Unless you can use the freshdesk wordpress addon, you probably cannot embed the full freshdesk in your portal. So your options are a bit more restricted: 1) Have you looked at the widgets that freshdesk provides? The issue will be knowing which ticket to show though. So what about:

Comment: 2) Freshdesk has a rest api you can query. So if you make sure you have a way to know the freshdesk user id of the user that's using your portal, you can use the `/api/v2/tickets?requester_id=[id]` endpoint to get a list of tickets the user has created. The ticket the user is currently looking at inside the iframe should be there as well. So I hope that that will allow you to know the correct ticket number and hence, change the src into the correct one.

Comment: I figured it out actually kind of based around your answer. I'm going to post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Shilly and a bit of brainstorming, I figured out a solution to my problem, and am posting it here for anyone else in my situation. Turns out that Freshdesk (the website inside the iframe) allows you to use custom javascript. Using this functionality, I came up with the following:

1) use parent.postMessage on first page load to send the URL of the currently active page to my main website.

2) use sessionStorage to store the URL of the current Freshdesk page on my website

3) on first page load of my main website, check to see if a sessionStorage value is set, and if so, set the iFrame's src to this value.

It's not quite a true "only on refresh" solution, however it does make the last iFrame page visited persist throughout the remainder of the user's session, which means they won't lose their place if refreshing or navigating away temporarily. Thanks to the use of sessionStorage, this will also reset back when the user closes the page, meaning on their next visit they'll restart at the Freshdesk home page (or whatever other website you're hosting inside the iFrame).